# Access delay to children after a MutationObserver on a created element in the DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

Well, Hi everyone for my first post here :)

I will try to be as clear as possible, because the problem encountered is just...
(English is not my native language, sorry if it's not perfect)

I'm working on a website, after a while of user's inactivity, a Chatbox appears. It's not present in the DOM at beginning and doesn't appear with a simple CSS class. It creates a new block div in the DOM with the ID "mychatcontainer", so to catch it, I'm using a mutation observer, below my code (it's not perfect, I'm not done with it, but it do the work I need for the moment :))

```
var target = document.getElementById('page13621');
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations){
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation){
    if (mutation.addedNodes[0].id === "mychatcontainer") {
      console.log(mutation.type);
      console.log(mutation.addedNodes);
      console.log(mutation.addedNodes[0]);
      console.log(document.getElementById("mychatcontainer"));      
      console.log(this.document.getElementById("mychatcontainer"));
    }
  });    
});
var config = { attributes: false, childList: true, characterData: true, subtree: true };
observer.observe(target, config);
```

[**Here is the result of console.log**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RF8Pw.png)

As you can see, it only shows

```
<div id="mychatcontainer"></div>
```

without the possibilty to access to children and so the part which is interresting me.

Whereas if I do it manually with my browser console I get all the information **and the access to children !!**

[**Manual result**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/937Xg.png)

- So first question here, am I missing a point ?!

The second thing on which I want to catch your attention is :
When yesterday I tried my code on my personnal Network, console.log were having an access to children but only on first try, then when I relaod the page, the same problem occurs, **No access to children**

- So second question, what is that ? So crazy...

Thanks for your attention, hope someone could help me :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, I found a solution even if I don't like it, I guess that in my case I don't have the choice..

As you can see below I add a setTiemout function with 1.2 seconds, I can't reduce that time unfortunatly, but at the end I have access to children's elements.

```
var target = document.getElementById('page13621');
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations){
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation){
    if (mutation.addedNodes[0].id === "#ID_of_created_block") {
      //add a setTiemout function
      myFunction();
    }
  });    
});
var config = { attributes: false, childList: true, characterData: true, subtree: true };
observer.observe(target, config);

var myFunction = function() {
  setTimeout(function(){
    // Here add your code, in my exemple it was my console.log
  }, 1200);
}
```

**Can someone confirm me that it exist a time of synchronization between the existing DOM et the created one ?** Which is explaining this 1.2 seconds delay.

A tip for devs, don't create new elements in the DOM during user experience. Create all at the beginning then hide or show it. Like that the access to children is without delay.

Thanks for your attention, everything to improve my solution is welcome :)